# AlpineJS component breaks on requests

Tags: laravel

i have a small app made in Laravel 10, using Livewire and Alpinejs.
I'm having an issue with the a AlpineJs component, the main job of this component is to show me dynamically the wait time of an attention ticket. As an example it would be 00:01, 00:02 etc.

The main issue is that when i made a request and the component reloads sometimes it doesn't show the time at all.

```
        <script>

            window.Alpine = Alpine
 
            // Alpine.start()
            function clock(timeDifferenceInSeconds) {

                let date = new Date()

                return {
                    timeDifference: Date.parse(timeDifferenceInSeconds),
                    formattedTime: '',
                    intervalId: null, // Store the interval ID for later clearing

                    startClock() {
                        // Clear existing interval
                        this.clearClock();

                        // Update formattedTime periodically based on timeDifference
                        this.intervalId = setInterval(() => {
                            const currentTime = new Date();
                            const userCreationTime = new Date(currentTime.getTime() - this.timeDifference);

                            // Format the time as "mm:ss"
                            this.formattedTime = this.formatTime(userCreationTime);
                        }, 1000); // Update every second
                    },

                    clearClock() {
                        // Clear the interval if it's set
                        if (this.intervalId !== null) {
                            clearInterval(this.intervalId);
                            this.intervalId = null;
                        }
                    },

                    formatTime(time) {
                        // Get minutes and seconds
                        // const hours = time.getHours().toString().padStart(1, '0');
                        const minutes = time.getMinutes().toString().padStart(2, '0');
                        const seconds = time.getSeconds().toString().padStart(2, '0');

                        // console.log(hours);

                        // Return the formatted time
                        return `${minutes}:${seconds}`;
                    },
                };
```

Alpine Component

```
                <td class="whitespace-nowrap px-1 py-1">
                    <span 
                        class="px-1 text-slate-500 font-semibold" 
                        x-data="clock('{{$numero->created_at}}')" 
                        x-init="clearClock(), startClock()" 
                        x-text="formattedTime">
                    </span>
                </td>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0FVbq.jpg)